# Getting the error 0x80370102 when trying to run WSL on Windows 11 on Mac

Tags: virtualization, mac, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, parallels

I installed Windows 11 on my Mac (M1) using Parallels, and on the windows machine I tried installing the Ubuntu subsystem to run Docker, so I downloaded Ubuntu (Ubuntu2004-220404) and installed it. However, I received the following error message:

> "WslRedisterDistribution failed with an error: 0x80370102. Please
> enable the virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure
> virtualization is enabled in the BIOS."

I read several articles about that, but I wasn't able to fix the problem, which I think might be because I'm using a virtual machine.

Comment: If you think this is possible and you need more help, please edit your question and include more details. You should share the research you've found. You should also include a description of all of the steps you've already taken. Include the commands you are using.  Please continue to post error messages, but also the steps you need to take to reproduce that error

Comment: @Nmath I did not find any reference.  
The project I'm working on doesn't run on macOS, so I'm using Windows. And I have to install Redis, but I read that it is only possible to install Redis on Ubuntu. Could you suggest another solution?  
Perhaps I should try installing Ubuntu on my Mac using a virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

When attempting to enable the WSL2 *"Virtual Machine Platform"* inside another virtual machine, you'll need what's known as "Nested Virtualization".

Parallels [supports nested virtualization](https://kb.parallels.com/116239), but only on Intel processors, and only then on Pro and Business Editions.  Since those versions support Hyper-V, in theory they will also support the the WSL2 Virtual Machine Platform, since it is a subset of Hyper-V functionality.

But no, with an M1, you will not be able to run WSL2 inside Parallels.

However, you mention in the comments wanting to run Redis under Ubuntu, and my understanding from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476945/how-do-i-run-redis-on-windows) is that it will work under WSL1 as well, so you may not necessarily *need* WSL2 in this instance.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.

Comment: @Lioo7 Most certainly.  Note that there might still be a WSL/Ubuntu option for you on Parallels.  I was in the middle of typing up some additional info when I got pulled away, so I do hope you see it.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that.